# Issue while building an object of type GetRequest for elasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use ReactiveElasticsearchClient for connecting to my elastic search.

As per the doc's 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-get.html

I understood I can create a request like

```
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(
        "posts", 
        "1")
```

But I have to pass my query also as a body to the request. How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused by the wording: Get API. The "Get API" in ES docs is about getting a document, not a generic GET request (as in HTTP).

What you're after is this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/_search_apis.html